# javascript set value to Associative Arrays

Tags: javascript

how set value in javascript to Associative Arrays?

Why in this case i get error: "car[0] is undefined"

```
var car = new Array();
car[0]['name'] = 'My name';
```

Comment: Please not that "associative arrays" are just plain objects and that you should not use `new Array()` due its ambiguity.

Comment: I did not think of that... @user319854, did you actually want to have car be the associative array? as in var car = {name:'My name'}; maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you never defined `car[0]`. You have to initialize it with an (empty) object:

```
var car = [];
car[0] = {};
car[0]['name'] = 'My name';
```

Another solution would be this:

```
var car = [{name: 'My Name'}];
```

or this one:

```
var car = [];
car[0] = {name: 'My Name'};
```

or this one:

```
var car = [];
car.push({name: 'My Name'});
```

Comment: Semicolons are usually not necessary in JavaScript but since [ASI](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) is one of the worst things JavaScript has I've added them (just forgot them).

Comment: +1 use of object and array litterals will be much more readable indeed.

Comment: @Eric: I think you did -1 instead of +1.

Comment: +1 *(nothing more to say :))* (oh: shame on the downvoter, this answer is 100% correct).

Answer (score 3):

```
var car = [];
car.push({
    'name': 'My name'
});
```

Comment: Fyi, quoting keys in object literals is optional as long as they don't collide with certain reserved keywords.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, yup -- but with quotes you're also able to create object literals with special characters (like -). So it's safer to always use them.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking two steps at once: the item 0 in the car array is undefined. You need an object to set the value of the 'name' property.

You can initialize an empty object in car[0] like this:

```
car[0] = {};
```

There is no need to call the Array() constructor on the first line. This could be written:

```
var car = [];
```

and if you want to have an object in the array:

```
var car = [{}];
```

Answer (score 0):

in your example, `car[0]` is not initialized and it is `undefined`, and `undefined` variables cannot have properties (after all, setting an associative array's value means setting the object's method).

Comment: Not  *method* but *property*.